# Fuzzy membership output different in arcpy and desktop

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2

I am running a fuzzy membership on multiple rasters with the following code:

```
arcpy.env.workspace=r'F:\Sheyenne\Normalized_Indices\NDII'
NDIIout='F:\Sheyenne\Normalized_Indices\Fuzzy_Membership\NDII\\'
NDIIList=arcpy.ListRasters('*.tif')
for ndiiraster in NDIIList:
    outpath=NDIIout + ndiiraster
    outraster=arcpy.gp.FuzzyMembership_sa(ndiiraster, outpath, "FuzzyLarge", "NONE")
```

the code executes fine but when I look at the results they are not what I expect.  The low values of my input raster are being assigned high values in the output and visa versa.  This should not be the case as I am using "FuzzyLarge".  When I run the same process in ArcGIS desktop the result is what I expect though.  Would anyone know why this isn't executing properly in arcpy?

Comment: A good way to troubleshoot differences between ArcMap tools and Python tools is to go to the *Results* pane, right click on your tool run and press *Copy as Python snippet*. If you compare this code to what you wrote, you should see something different.

Comment: @dmahr  I think that could be added as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @dmahr:

> A good way to troubleshoot differences between ArcMap tools and Python
>   tools is to go to the *Results* pane, right click on your tool run and
>   press *Copy as Python snippet*. If you compare this code to what you
>   wrote, you should see something different.